# definition of "operator +=" behaving unexpectedly

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-overloading

## Brief

I am defining my own `String` class. Everything works fine except for my definition of `+=` which I intend to use to concatenate `Strings`

```
//expected behaviour
String c = "foo";
String d = "lala";

c+=d;
cout<<c;
```

Should output:

```
foolala
```

I am having an issue with it as it does seem to work correctly except for the last bit where it seems to not be passing the pointer.

Here is the code (I have omitted most of the other definitions as I don't think they are useful for this)

---

## Code

```
class String{

    private:
        unsigned int SizeS;
        char *Buffer;

    public:
        String():SizeS(0){}

        String(unsigned int i):SizeS(i){Buffer=new char[SizeS];}

        String(const char *string)
        {
            //defines the initialiser
            SizeS = strlen(string);                 //find out the length of the string
            Buffer = new char[SizeS];               //allocate space for the entire string+1 for terminator
            memcpy(Buffer,string,SizeS);            //copy to buffer the whole thing
            Buffer[SizeS]=0;                        //terminate the buffer with an end character
        }

        char * GetBuffer() const { return this->Buffer; }

        String (const String& copied) :SizeS(copied.SizeS)
        {
            // defines how copying  works
            Buffer = new char[SizeS];
            memcpy(Buffer,copied.Buffer,SizeS);
        }


        // this is where the issue is ------------------
        String* operator += (const String& to_concat)
        {
            unsigned int newSize = this->SizeS + to_concat.SizeS;
            String *p = new String(newSize) ;
            memcpy(p->Buffer,this->Buffer,this->SizeS);
            memcpy(p->Buffer+this->SizeS,to_concat.Buffer,to_concat.SizeS);

            std::cout<<p->Buffer<<std::endl;

            return p;
        }
        // this is where the issue ends ------------------
};

std::ostream&  operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const String& other) { stream << other.GetBuffer(); return stream; }


int main()
{
    String c="foo";
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
    c += c;
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
}
```

#### Expected Output

```
foo
foofoo
foofoo
```

#### Actual Output

```
foo 
foofoo
foo
```

---

## Question

What am I doing wrong? From my understanding, I am overwritting the pointer `c` with the pointer `p`, but it seems as though `c` does not change. Why is that ?

---

## Solution

After reading the comments and suggestion I came up with this solution which works.

```
        String& operator += (const String& to_concat)
        {
            unsigned int newSize = this->SizeS + to_concat.SizeS;
            char* p = new char[newSize];

            memcpy(p,this->Buffer,this->SizeS);
            memcpy(p+this->SizeS,to_concat.Buffer,to_concat.SizeS);

            delete[](this->Buffer);

            this->Buffer=p;
            this->SizeS=newSize;

            return *this;
        }
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code e.g. the missing constructor. Questions should contain a [mcve]

Comment: You should concatinate the result into *this->Buffer

Comment: You need to check all your memory allocations and writing of zero (nul) terminators - they are not working consistently.   Your constructors allocate `Buffer` as `SizeS+1` characters and finishes by writing to `Buffer[SizeS+1]`.   That causes undefined behaviour.   Your `operator+=()` has the opposite problem - it doesn't allocate enough characters to store the nul character, but also doesn't write the nul character to the buffer.   Your `operator<<()` and the output statement in `operator+=()` both assume the nul terminator is present, and has undefined behaviour if it is not ...

Comment: And don't get me started on the fact that `operator+=()` returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated `String`.   That is a memory leak waiting to happen.

Comment: @Peter It's not waiting; the memory leak is right there in the program.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the input. I am now going to rationalise it and correct the post. Indeed it was a bit all over the place, but I couldn’t test it prior to this conversation as it was not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't write any code to change `c`.

There is no "pointer `c`" and, even if there were, you'd not be overwriting it.

Your `+=` creates a new, dynamically allocated string, using the data from the original two strings, then returns a pointer to it which your program then throws away (incidentally, leaking that new string).

Instead of creating and returning `p`, you should be modifying the buffer in `this` (then, conventionally, returning `*this` as a `String&` to permit chaining).

Also, a `+=` operator should not produce output.

---

A `+` operator could work similarly to how you've done it, since they're supposed to produce new objects, but you shouldn't actually use `new` for that — you'd still have a memory leak. Try to avoid dynamic allocation (though you're going to need to dynamically allocate the buffer that each `String`'s `buffer` pointer point to).

Comment: Would allocating more space in `this` not be bad practice? Would I not run into the risk of writing over something which is at the end of that register?

Comment: If the new string does not fit into your old object, then you must reallocate your buffer or refuse to perform that operation. It is your duty as class designer to manage the memory.

Comment: @cstml What register?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I am sorry, my comment actually is completely wrong , misunderstood your suggestion. I now understand where the issue is and how to solve it. Will post an updated edit of the corrected source.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings and by register I meant memory block. In my misunderstanding I thought you were saying to add them to the same memory block.

Comment: @cstml No, that's why you allocate more space.